# Equivalent of '&' for ifelse statements in r

Tags: r

I want to create a new column in a data frame that multiplies three variables together and divides by three others. If the dividing variables equal 0, I want to leave them out. So this is what I was doing:

```
sm3$mult=ifelse(sm3$WS==0, (sm3$RF*sm3$EF*sm3$HD/sm3$M/sm3$ESF), 
            ifelse(sm3$M==0, (sm3$RF*sm3$EF*sm3$HD/sm3$WS/sm3$ESF), 
            ifelse(sm3$ESF==0,(sm3$RF*sm3$EF*sm3$HD/sm3$WS/sm3$M),
            (sm3$RF*sm3$EF*sm3$HD/sm3$WS/sm3$M/sm3$ESF))))
```

But sometimes more than one of the dividing variables equals 0, so if that is the case, I want to leave both out. So I tried this, but it is not working:

```
sm3$mult=ifelse(sm3$WS==0, (sm3$RF*sm3$EF*sm3$HD/sm3$M/sm3$ESF), 
            ifelse(sm3$M==0, (sm3$RF*sm3$EF*sm3$HD/sm3$WS/sm3$ESF), 
            ifelse(sm3$ESF==0,(sm3$RF*sm3$EF*sm3$HD/sm3$WS/sm3$M), 
            ifelse(sm3$WS==0 & sm3$M==0,(sm3$RF*sm3$EF*sm3$HD/sm3$ESF), 
            ifelse(sm3$WS==0 & sm3$ESF==0,(sm3$RF*sm3$EF*sm3$HD/sm3$M), 
            ifelse(sm3$M==0 & sm3$ESF==0,(sm3$RF*sm3$EF*sm3$HD/sm3$WS), 
            ifelse(sm3$WS==0 & sm3$M==0 & sm3$WS==0,(sm3$RF*sm3$EF*sm3$HD), 
            (sm3$RF*sm3$EF*sm3$HD/sm3$WS/sm3$M/sm3$ESF))))))))
```

No errors come up, it just spits out the same output as the one above (which is not what I want).

There is probably a much easier way to do this (which I would love to hear about), but I also want to know why '&' doesn't work and if there is anything that works instead. Lots of googling hasn't turned up anything useful. Thank you very much

Comment: `&` works just fine inside `ifelse`. The problem is your logic. The statements will be checked outside in, so your first condition is `WS == 0`. If that is true, then you define a result on your first line. Then you go on to check other conditions, and some of them you also check if `WS == 0` which *will not be true again* because you already caught all of those cases.

Comment: You have 3 variables each of which will be 0 or not 0 - hence 2^3 = 8 possible combinations. You could code logic for each of them (you have tried to), but it's asking for bugs and doesn't scale at all - what would you do if next week you were asked to do the same analysis with 6 variables? Type out all 64 cases and hope you didn't make mistakes? No. You need a better way.

Comment: That said, in understanding the problems with your code, I think it would work if you started with `WS == 0 & M == 0 & ESF == 0` (most restrictive case) and reversed the order of your conditions. Check the triple 0 first, then the double 0s, then the single 0s. Also you have a bug in your last line where you have two `WS == 0` checks and no `ESF == 0`.

Comment: And this is a great use-case for `with` to keep you from typing `sm3` 50+ times. Your code could be `sm3$mult = with(sm3, ifelse(WS == 0 & ESF == 0 & M == 0, ...))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the dividing columns and convert all 0s to 1s

For example, if you have this data frame

```
a = c(2,3,4,0)
b = c(5,0,2,1)
c = c(0,4,2,3)

d = data.frame(a,b,c)

> d
  a b c
1 2 5 0
2 3 0 4
3 4 2 2
4 0 1 3
```

and you want to divide `a` by `b` and `c` replace all zeros in b and c by 1

```
d$b[d$b==0] = 1
d$c[d$c==0] = 1

d$e = d$a/d$b/d$c
```

Result:

```
> d
  a b c    e
1 2 5 1 0.40
2 3 1 4 0.75
3 4 2 2 1.00
4 0 1 3 0.00
```

If you don't want to modify your columns make a copy of them, do the substitution and then erase the copies.

Comment: Oh, that's obvious now you point it out. Great! Is there a way of doing the equivalent of '&' with ifelse statements though?